# How to add reaction to everything that certain user says

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

Hi i have a problem because i want to add reaction to everything that certain user says but it unfortunately doesn't work and i have no idea why. Can somehone help me?

```
import discord

client = discord.Client()


@client.event
    async def on_ready():
    print('I logged in as: {0.user}'.format(client))


@client.event
    async def on_message(msg):
    if msg.author == 'user id here':
        await msg.add_reaction('')


client.run('token')
```

Comment: `msg.author.id`

Answer (score 1):

`msg.author` returns the author's discord tag, not the ID.

Use `msg.author.id` instead.